# Is there any good reason not to increase upload_max_filesize and post_max_size?

Tags: apache-2.2, php, upload

As the sysadmin of a LAMP box I am being asked to raise the upload capacity of php/html forms to something around 70 MB. I believe the server can handle it since it has two quad cores and 4 Gig RAM. I also don't have any costly bandwidth limitation. So, since the limit in the standard php.ini is usually at 2MB I wonder, is there any other issue I should consider before changing my upload_max_filesize and post_max_size or can I go with it safely?

Thanks for any hint!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is mostly a problem if you have limited ram and multiple users doing uploads at the same time. Both of those are per session, so a user starting a slow upload can eat up quite a bit or resources for you for a long time.

If you have over 40 or so users doing uploads/big posts at the maximum size you will run into problems. Otherwise it shouldn't be any issue increasing those variables.